# root account access

Tags: root

when you install ubuntu it only asked for a user account name and password. how do I switch to the root account within terminal server. I try the SU and then enter the only password I created. I have also tried SU root and the only password I created and it comes back with authentication failure. I can log in with my user account and use the only password created. what gives?

Answer (score 1):

use `sudo -s`. `su` alone asks for the superuser password, `sudo` asks for your password. The parameter `-s` opens a new shell as `root`.